# Is the Radical Line defined Inside two Intersecting Circles?

Tags: soft-question, terminology, circles

It is given that, the [radical line](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RadicalLine.html) of two intersecting circles is the common chord of the two circles. In strict terminology, does the radical line refer to the region only outside the circles and the common chord only inside the two circles? Is there any strict terminology for radical line definition for outside or inside points, like a circle usually refers only the boundary, whereas a disc represents the region? Or the term radical line is used interchangeably with common chord in case of intersecting circles?

Comment: We call it radical axis, common chord, common tangent in different circumstances. But how does it even matter? In all cases Power of point wrt both circles is same

Comment: @user600016, We sometimes call the region bounded by a circle as circle. But in strict terminology, the region bounded by the curve circle is called a disc. Even though this doesn't matter a lot, it is good to learn the right terminologies to avoid confusion when communicating. I hope you understood.

Comment: I think, it's important to give attention to small details like this and I feel there is nothing wrong in that. That's why I included the tag "soft-question".

Comment: What is "given" (in the Mathworld entry you reference) is that the radical line is "the locus of points of equal circle power with respect to two nonconcentric circles". ... One *deduces* that this locus is, in fact, a line. When the circles overlap, the line is conveniently the one containing the common chord (because the points of intersection have circle power zero wrt the circles); for tangent or disjoint circles, it takes a little more explaining than this comment space allows. ... Nevertheless, a "radical line" is always a *complete* line. To discuss the chord, just say "common chord".